# Css pseudo-classes without any selector, is it ok?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors

Selector like

```
.some-class :first-child
```

which selects the first child inside `.some-class` works as expected in all browsers, even in the IE8.

But mobile Chrome's 'Reduce data option' removes a space between `.some-class` and `:first-child` and breaks the CSS by applying styles to `.some-class` element itself. In other cases like `.class1 .class2` Chrome keeps the space intact. Probably, it considers the space between `.some-class` and `:first-child` to be a non-semantic space, because it thinks that there can't be a pseudo-class without some kind of a selector.

But I've checked the standard and it doesn't say anywhere that pseudo-class must have a selector. At the same time all examples with pseudo-classes include an element selector, like

```
p:first-child
```

So I'm confused. Is this CSS selector incorrect or is there a bug in Chrome's 'Reduce data usage'?

Comment: "there a bug in Chrome's 'Reduce data usage'" <-- This.

Comment: Wow, you really can't make this up. This is IE9-level nonsense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:first-child` is valid as a standalone selector and this appears to be a bug in the mobile version of Chrome. We can confirm this with [W3C's CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator).

> ```css
> :first-child { background: #F00; }
> ```
>
> Congratulations! No Error Found.

In fact, everything listed in the *Selectors* section of the [Selectors Level 3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) is valid as a standalone selector. I imagine the reason the examples for `:first-child` also include an element selector is to avoid confusion and to show how it can be used on that particular element.

Comment: @james-donelly thanks for the extensive answer! I've reported the issue to Google and attached a link to this SO question.

Comment: A pseudo-class is valid by itself because it is a simple selector, just like a class selector or an ID selector is valid on its own. A selector that does not begin with a type selector is said to have an implicit `*` selector instead. This includes pseudo-elements (e.g. `*, :before, :after { box-sizing: border-box; }`).

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it's a bug. 
You should be able to work around it with 
.some-class *:first-child